# Setting octomap resolution doesn't work

Tags: rviz, moveit, octomap, ros-kinetic, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with ROS kinetic and implemented perception with octomap like described in http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/perception_pipeline/perception_pipeline_tutorial.html . However, when I am changing octomap_resolution in my launch file, the generated octomap doesn't change the resolution. It looks like it's always using the default value of 0.05. I checked the value with rosparam get just after starting the launch file and after receiving the point cloud. At both times it shows the value I've set but the result shown in RViz still does use the default value. Any ideas where I am wrong or what I could check to get some ideas?
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328575/setting-octomap-resolution-doesn%27t-work/) by [Krebsileinchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34851/krebsileinchen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2019-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the solution. I had to set the parameter /move_group/octomap_resolution instead of only octomap_resolution.

---

Originally posted by [Krebsileinchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34851/krebsileinchen/) with karma: 51 on 2019-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0